# How to match everything after slash to use as an nginx rewrite?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have these test cases:

```
/test
/test/
/test/whatever
```

I would like to write an nginx rewrite rule that only targets `/test/whatever`

I currently have

`rewrite ^/(test/)(.*) /some-other-page;` but this targets all the above cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `^/test/(.+)`.

Comment: Damnit, that was simple. Thank you. If u post it as an answer ill accept it. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew damm this guy is so quick. cheers mate missed by a wishker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^/(test/)(.*)`  will match `/test/` because `.*` can match an empty string.

You may use

```
^/test/(.+)
```

The `.+` will require at least 1 char after `/test/`.